# Wp-Stateless + Google Cloud Storage view but not download files

Tags: wordpress, cloud, storage

I want to use Google Cloud Storage (GCS) to share my videos on my WordPress LMS, for that, I am using WP-Stateless which during setup which requires to provide public access to my GCS bucket.

Now my issue is that I want my users to be able to view the media files but not be able to download them.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to prevent users from downloading images from your website. In fact when users view your images in a browser, they are downloaded to your browser cache. You can take some measures like:

1. Prevent right click
2. Disable hotlinking
3. Add a watermark
4. Add a copyright notice etc etc...

But realistically there is not much you can do. Everything you do to protect your images can be bypassed. You could also use a plugin to convert your images to webp format. Most people do not like downloading webp. They prefer jpg and png :)